# Fahrenheit to Celsius table temperature converter in C

Tags: c

I am brand new to programming in C. I am following along with the book "The C Programming Language, Second Edition." I am making my own modifications to the example code presented in the book as I go along. Anyway I am posting my code here for review because I want to make sure I am off to a good start. There a few things in particular that I want to make sure that I am doing right as to not develop any future bad habits:

1. I would like to make sure I am adhering to the C standards. Based on my research I found that the current and most recent standard for C is C17 or ISO/IEC 9899:2018, please correct me if I am wrong. As a result I have been compiling the code with the following parameters: `gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors -std=c17 source.c` Is this a good practice?
2. I know I am a beginner but I would like to make sure that I am doing even the simplest things in a clean and efficient way.

So if I can get a review on this code sample, that would be great.

```
/* This program uses the formula C = (5/9)(F-32) to print a table of Farenheit
 * temperatures and their Centigrade or Celsius equivalents. Adapted from:
 * Kernighan, B. W., & Ritchie, D. M. (1988). The C programming language. */

#include <stdio.h>

/* Print Fahrenheit-Celsius table for Fahrenheit = 0, 20, ..., 300. */

int main(void)
{
    float fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;   /* Lower limit of temperature table. */
    upper = 300; /* Upper limit. */
    step = 20;   /* Step size. */

    printf("Fahrenheit to Celsius\n"); /* Table header */
    printf("%3s %6s\n", "F", "C");     /* Temperature label */

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);
        printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a copy of K&R ready, but how much of the code provided is theirs and how much of it is yours?

Comment: In a real application you'd generate all these values at compile time and store them in a read-only array. But if you are an absolute beginner, you'll need to study arrays and loops first :)

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Lundin Really? I don't think it's possible to claim that a compile-time table is desirable over a simple loop in all cases. It depends on what you're optimizing for and what architecture you're on. The runtime-generated loop is much simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: @Reinderien There's always exceptions, but generally, on almost all systems from low end microcontrollers to high end 64 bit CPUs, execution time is much more valuable than read-only memory.

Comment: @Lundin I've ran out of memory often enough on a microcontroller to know that wasn't always true, but on modern systems (even embedded) there's usually a bit more (EEP)ROM available. It's all a matter of how it's used in the field. Considering this is more of an exercise, it's good for OP to be aware of both possibilities and get experience with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's great that you're using C17.
- Your `gcc` mostly looks sane, though I would add `-ggdb` and start learning about `gdb`.
- Since you are using above-C99, I would rewrite

```
    float fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;   /* Lower limit of temperature table. */
    upper = 300; /* Upper limit. */
    step = 20;   /* Step size. */
```

as

```
    const int lower = 0,   // Lower limit of temperature table.
              upper = 300, // Upper limit.
              step = 20;   // Step size.
```

and move `fahr` to a `for` index:

```
for (double fahr = lower; fahr <= upper; fahr += step)
```

Also, due to the semantics of float promotion,

```
(5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0)
```

can just be

```
(fahr - 32)*5/9
```

This:

```
printf("Fahrenheit to Celsius\n"); /* Table header */
printf("%3s %6s\n", "F", "C");     /* Temperature label */
```

can use implicit string concatenation and character fields:

```
printf(
    "Fahrenheit to Celsius\n"  // Table header
    "%3c %6c\n",               // Temperature label 
    'F', 'C'
);
```

Comment: This was really great. Thank you. I am going to look into gdb, I ran the -ggdb flag but didn't notice anything different.

Comment: It's been rolled back - rather than doing that, if you want another round of review you should post a new question.

Comment: Several declarations on a single line is generally considered bad practice/bad style since it increases the chance of bugs when using const, pointers etc. Mixing fixed point integer constants with floating point is considered very bad style since it's very easy to get integer promotion bugs. Your string concatenation example makes the code harder too read and there's no need for such pre-mature optimizations in a simple program like this. Overall, lots of bad and/or subjective advise, I have to down vote.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to make sure I am off to a good start.

**`float` vs `double`**

Save `float` for cases when serious reduced memory needed or when performance has compelled the use of narrow floating point, else use `double` as the go-to floating point type.

**Units**

300 what?
Physical units deserve clarity, perhaps a comment, in code.  Be clear or [oops!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure).

```
// upper = 300; /* Upper limit. */
upper = 300 /* F */; /* Upper limit. */
```

---

> make sure I am adhering to the C standards.

**Warnings**

Using a modern compiler with many, if not all, warnings enabled is a *good* thing.  Maybe add `-Wetra`.

---

> make sure that I am doing even the simplest things in a clean and efficient way.

**Overall**

Code looks very clean and mostly efficient.

**Unnecessary FP mixed operations**

Notice by using `float` objects, yet `double` constants, code is like below incurring up and down FP conversions.

```
celsius = (float)((5.0/9.0) * ((double)fahr-32.0));
printf("%3.0f %6.1f\n", (double)fahr, (double)celsius);
```

If wanting to stay with `float`, use `float` constants

```
celsius = (5.0f/9.0f) * (fahr-32.0f);
```

---

**Idea: abstract formatting**

```
#define F_WIDTH1 3
#define C_WIDTH2 6

printf("%*s %*s\n", F_WIDTH, "F", C_WIDTH, "C");
...
    printf("%*.0f %*.1f\n", F_WIDTH, fahr, C_WIDTH, celsius);
```

Comment: This is great thank you. I am definitely going to implement and look further into your suggestions. I understand the float vs double suggestion but need to do further research into abstract formatting as I am not yet familiar with that one.

Comment: The float vs double constant problem is inherited from K&R. Your review makes several valid points but what you are actually reviewing is the verbatim of K&R. K&R apparently didn't know the difference between float and double either... it's such a harmful book.

Comment: @Lundin In K&R defense, at the time, all FP was typically very expensive vs. integer math.  Somewhat true today, but often a a greatly lesser degree.  ( I still use `float` primarily on embedded task lacking HW FP.) Benefits of `float` .v `double` _were_ more significant.  Agree K&R as a C primer today is at best: questionable.

Comment: Is there a more modern and relevant book you guys recommend?

Comment: @drebrb Although not a good primer, access to the C spec (or a draft of it) is very useful as it is definitive.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica are you referring to iso9899:2017?

Comment: @drebrb Yes, Also see [latest ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11504332/2410359) and other via various web searches.